# wcf service reference code generation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, projects-and-solutions

i have few project that use the same wcf service, my asp.net and test project are working fine
with the wcf service i add.

my new project in mvc asp.net also added the wcf reference , all of those project reuse 
the assemblies.

when there was compiler error with the types i saw difference in the reference.cs file and
the order that visual studio generate the code wasn't the same.

```
    // CODEGEN: Parameter 'GetLookupTablesResult' requires additional schema information that cannot be captured using the parameter mode. The specific attribute is 'System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute'.
```

this is the working one:

```
Runtime Version:4.0.30319.18063
```

this one not generate :

```
Runtime Version:4.0.30319.18444
```

why there is difference ? is it something in the solution settings?

Comment: `all of those project reuse the assemblies`, Are you sure for all assemblies in all projects?

Comment: yes , because i want to return some wrapper class in the service whice i pass this wrapper class to the client also , but the mvc project generate this wrapper also

Comment: One is attribute for `DataContract` & another one is for `ServiceContract`. Are you sure this should be same :)

Comment: you right ill updat the post

Comment: i update my question after i found some diffrence

Comment: two things that can create problems. Is your datacontracts has inheritance among them? Is service & contract have different assembly?  First try delete & add service reference again... if that not works.. this might be issue due to first two aforementioned issues, we will work on that...